# How to build authorization url for Instagram in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

How can I properly create a URL to redirect users for authorization on Instagram? As per the documentation, I should build a URL like this one

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize
  ?client_id=990602627938098
  &redirect_uri=https://socialsizzle.herokuapp.com/auth/
  &scope=user_profile,user_media
  &response_type=code
```

the problem is that if I do router.push with this URL in the browser I get something like that

```
https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize%20%20?client_id=459043345069265++&redirect_uri=https://mineral-one.vercel.app/++&scope=user_profile,user_media++&response_type=code
```

The problem is with thos %20%20 after authorize and those ++ before "&" do you know how to properly build URL in Next and redirect to it on page load?

Thanks

Comment: that happens because there are empty spaces in your url string. empty space gets encoded as %20.

Comment: single line, no spaces: `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=https://socialsizzle.herokuapp.com/auth/&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code`

Comment: please do not post real api keys (hope those are altered)

Comment: thank you I have changed it its not valid :)

Comment: Use URLSearchParams and URL to correctly build a url. Never just concatenate strings.